# Android jni : java compiler doesn't work

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-ndk

On building ndk project in eclipse, I received an error : '`A resource exists with a different case`'

It seems that eclipse doesn't run javac.exe ;;;

but ndk-build work (I checked .so file)

I tried removing CDT builder of builders of eclipse's setting, then eclipse compile NOTHING!

Could you tell me some advice?

Comment: this seems to have nothing to do with NDK; to understand the Java compiler's problem better, try to enable "verbose" output for Android, Java builders.

Comment: Did you build other projets with ndk before?
If you are using Windows you should download and set path to SDK, NDK, JDK, Ant, Cygwin, update SDK and set JAVA_HOME on Windows.